# Linq to SQL and Azure fails to return a record I know to be there

Tags: c#, linq, azure

Title says it. In the code below I get an exception on insert for a duplicate PK value. It happens extremely rarely but enough that it's once per week or more with 100+ users.

```
var prefs = userPrefs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == User.Id);
if (prefs == null) {
    // prefs = userPrefs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == User.Id);
    // LogSomethingIfPrefsIsNotNull();
    prefs = new UserPreferences { Id = User.Id, OtherProperties = Values };
    userPrefs.InsertOnSubmit(prefs);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I cannot fathom how the insert can fail. The PK is an integer however I have another table with two `string` fields for the key. It fails rarely as well.

I tried adding a duplicate check and logging (see commented lines). Low and behold it does indeed find the record on the second check and it does log.

How can this be possible? Nothing else is writing to the database.

[EDIT]: Per comments from @KasparsOzols and @JamieRees I looked into where this code is getting called. There was one that was inside an `HttpPost` method. I suppose a user could have double clicked a submit button to get this to happen. So let's ignore that one.

Another section of code works entirely differently. It's not in a section of code than can execute at the same time in another thread. It does not do a lookup of the primary key. Instead it does a lookup based on two other fields. If it doesn't find it, it does the insert. If we look at this table, there are duplicate records.

So the same logging I have commented out above was added. It verifies that the first call to `FirstOrDefault` fails yet the second call works.

I've posted the code below. In addition I've copied the *exact* code from a third place that is failing.

```
// Co-worker's code in another section that cannot be hit simultaneously.
// PK here is an ID field. Not alias or orgname.
// Logging code is removed for comments
shop = shopTable.FirstOrDefault(o => (o.OrgName.Equals(tempOrg) && o.AliasName.Equals(tempAlias)));
if (shop == null) {
   // Log that we didn't find it.
   var shop2 = shopTable.FirstOrDefault(o => (o.OrgName.Equals(tempOrg) && o.AliasName.Equals(tempAlias)));       
    // Log if we found it this time or not. This sometimes actually does find it.
}


// Additional code of mine that is also in an HttpPost.
// This code is an exact copy/paste from the app. The insert fails sometimes.
var charts = context.GetTable<MsoUserCharts>();
var chartRecord = charts.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Organization == organization && o.Username == username);
if (chartRecord == null) {
   chartRecord = StaticVariables.GetNewChartRecord(organization, username);
   charts.InsertOnSubmit(chartRecord);
   context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Possibly use `userPrefs.Any(u => u.Id == User.Id)` that will return a bool? Not sure it will make a difference.

Comment: Even if it works my entire app is broken. If `FirstOrDefault()` can't be trusted I'd always need to hack in an `Any()` statement before inserting any record. This has failed in a total of three spots so far. But there are 30+ tables used and many other places an insert could fail.

Comment: I have had no personal problems with `FirstOrDefault()` is it possible that 2 threads are executing that code at around the same time with the same `User.Id`?

Comment: In your code it looks like you're assigning the UserID to the preferences id. The preferences id should be auto assigned by the db, not your app.

Comment: Please specify when code above is called (per request, on user submit, etc). Also, if you are running on Azure and you have set up web site auto scaling, then this code might be executed on two different servers at around the same time. Also, make sure that you don't call `SubmitChanges` twice on the same instance of context as this could result in multiple inserts.

Comment: @Ricketts The user Id is assigned by the database. This is a piece of supporting data that can be added, and is in another table.

Comment: @KasparsOzols,  Jamie Rees - You guys may be on to something. I am noticing this code is in an HttpPost method where a submission has happened. So could the user be essentially double clicking the submit button? I will review the other spots this has happened at to see if they all share this in common.

Comment: It won't be double clicking submit if the db assigns the id.  If it were double clicking submit, you would get two inserts that are identical except the PK.

Comment: @Ricketts The DB already assigns the Id as I said before. It's done in another table though. This is a supporting table. And two identical records with different PKs is every bit as bad as a constraint error. In fact I'd rather have this error as it's easier to know something is wrong.

Comment: What I was saying is you can rule out double click. What you are experiencing is not symptoms of a double click if the table being inserted to has an auto generated pk.

Comment: @Ricketts Ok, I gotcha. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Could you specify how and when your DB context is created and how long it lives?

Comment: The context is created in the same method a few lines up. And it's inside a `using` block: `using (var context = new DataContext(cs))`.